# Add a link to the blog in the drop-down "help" menu in the top bar

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, top-bar, blog

In the upper-right corner, on the top navigation bar, there is a question mark in a circle that links to some useful sites:

[image: Information drop-down]

This is a feature request to add the [Stack Overflow blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/) to the list, on main and meta.

Answer (score 12):

There is a link to the blog in the site switcher menu:

[image]

Comment: Oh, thanks.  For some reason I missed that when looking around for such a link.

Comment: Good eye; I'd never noticed that link being there, either (mostly because my "Your Communities" is too long). Either way, I think having the blog in the "help" menu makes more sense than cramming it in the site-switcher menu. It isn't itself an SE community, but rather provides background info, announcements from the company, and, to some extent, help on using the sites themselves. As such, it belongs in the "help" menu. It is also more discoverable there, and could do with a short blurb explaining it's purpose. I'd recommend *removing* it from the site switcher and transplanting it into help.

Comment: @Cody: The help menu is the first one to fall off when the screen gets too small to hold all top bar icons. On my phone I don’t have a help menu.

Comment: It is reputation-dependent, @Cris. You have access to the review queues because of your rep level, so that menu item takes priority. I think that arrangement makes sense.

Comment: @Cody: I agree, I am not complaining about it. I’m saying (or rather implying, I wasn’t specific enough) that if they move the blog link to the help menu, I won’t have access to it any more.

Comment: @CodyGray: I visit the site almost regularly on my mobiles, but on my screen(first of all, I use the full theme) the review queues and the help button both are disabled. Idk why?

Comment: I don’t know, @light. I have all the icons in the top bar on my mobile screen. It’s not one of those absurdly big phones, either. Just an iPhone 6S in portrait mode. I have: inbox, achievements, reviews, help, and site switcher. I also even have room for the mod menu, plus the user card and a search icon. The responsive design is quite good here, in my experience.

Comment: I don't experience the same on both my smartpones, Redmi 5A, and Vivo v5. I just have search, user card, an inbox, achievements, and just site switcher.