# Adding a link to the Stack Overflow blog on side panel

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, blog, sidebar, community-bulletin

Can we add a link to the Stack Overflow blog here (side panel):

[image]

Right now, the easiest way to access the blog is to view an article and then navigate to other posts. The other way [described here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386759/add-a-link-to-the-blog-in-the-drop-down-help-menu-in-the-top-bar) was pretty hard to find:

[image]

Comment: And while we're at it, the alt text for the blog post links say "Meta Stack Exchange". Kind of odd.

Comment: I don't think that this is a top priority here but it could be done easily.

Comment: And a link to Meta/non-Meta?